# Photorealistic texturing in Building footprints using Ortho rectified satellite image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, rooftop-building

Is there any way of photorealistic texturing of 2D Building footprints with height field/3D building/Multipatch using ortho-rectified high resolution satellite image (Building Footprints Created from Same Images).
Basic requirement is to give texture in multiple buildings available in satellite images[image]

Comment: You can probably do the roofs but a satellite image isn't going to see much of the walls...

Comment: I've assumed that you are using ArcScene so I'm adding tags for that.

Comment: how to add roofs as high accuracy doesn't required. Can open source software/tool available do this? or we need to go with commercial software, please give the name of that software allows texturing from satellite image.

Comment: Roof texturing is done using Ortho rectified satellite image (https://www.geoplanit.co.uk/?p=470). Can anyone help how to give texture from angle projected image/aerial image/Angle projected satellite image